# Jquery Selecting image

Tags: jquery

primarily, i'm new for Jquery.

I have images like that . What i want is that  when user click image,it makes image bordered. User can select a number of images. It all must be bordered when selected. After button is clicked, i will have images id.

```
  <tr><img id="i will put value for db processing"src="urlofimage"</tr> &nbsp;
```

[image]

How can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$.fn.hasBorder = function() {   
  if ((this.outerWidth() - this.innerWidth() > 0) ||  (this.outerHeight() - this.innerHeight() > 0)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectedImgsArr = [];
   $("img").click(function() {

      if($(this).hasBorder()) {
          $(this).css("border", "");
          //you can remove the id from array if you need to
      }
      else {
         $(this).css("border", "1 px solid red");
         selectedImgsArr.push($(this).attr("id")); //something like this 
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: yes this will make image bordered, what i want is that selected images will send as array . How can i do that?

Comment: just one suggestion, It would be nice if the border goes when again clicked on the image

Comment: see edited code, that should work, but using class is much better solution for you

Answer (score 3):

a simple example:

[live example in JsBin](https://jsbin.com/yepigik/8/edit?html,js,output)

the styling:

```css
ul { list-style: none; }
ul li { display: inline; } 
ul li img { border: 2px solid white; cursor: pointer; }
ul li img:hover,
ul li img.hover { border: 2px solid black; }
```

the javascript:

```js
$(function() {

  $("img").click(function() {      
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");      
  });

  $("#btn").click(function() {      
    var imgs = $("img.hover").length;    
    alert('there are ' + imgs + ' images selected');        
  });

});
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for reporting, fixed the link 

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough, just add a new CSS class to the image on click.

```
<html>
...
<td><img class='galImages' src='urlofimage' /></td>
...
</html>

<script>
$document.ready(function() {
    $('img.galImages').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {  
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
</script>

<style>
.selected {
    1px solid #f00;
}
</style>
```

I prefer this method to in-script style definitions for the sake of simply removing stylistic elements from functionality. Makes everything reusable and easy to change later if need be. Above code supports both applying the formatting and removing it on a secondary click. (IE: It will remove if it exists.)

Answer (score 1):

give them all a class:

```
<tr><img class="clickable" id="i will put value for db processing" src="urlofimage" /></tr>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var clickedarray = new Array();
        $('.clickable').click(function() {
            //add border
            $(this).css({border: '1px solid #000'});
            //store in array
            clickedarray.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

first add a class for selections and then add items to array which have 'selected-image' class while form posted

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectedImgsArr = new Array();
   $("img").click(function() {

      if($(this).hasClass("selected-image"))
           $(this).removeClass("selected-image");
      else
           $(this).addClass("selected-image");
   });
   $("form").submit(function(){
       selectedImgsArr.push($(".selected-image").attr("src"));
   })
});
```

Comment: Do you mind translating that little bit of text in english so our quality inspectors don't go crazy?