# Selecting an Image with Javascript and pass it to a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can some one direct me on how to select an image iterated over from the database like seen here 
[[Jquery Selecting image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170280/jquery-selecting-image][1])
and on clicking the any of the image let it pass the clicked image to a textfield input box.

Is there a better way I can achieve that. Had been researching all day.
Kindly assist

Comment: Pass it to a textfield as what? The image itself?

Comment: yes to pass it (the image itself). - Altay

Comment: I'd recommend you to create a div for an issue like that. Do you necessarily need a textfield?

Comment: You can only pass text into a textfield

Comment: Not really! but need to add other text to it then send it back to the database.

Comment: Is there a way I can draw the image on the textfield just like smiley on the textfield chat panel. - LcSalazar

Comment: Can someone help in this challenge

Comment: Just take the longer route of putting the image in a div and have the text field seperately. You don't want to put the image blob and the text in the same database field anyway. So save yourself a few headaches and follow Altays advice.

Comment: I am thinking and working as per direction given. Is there a way I can use css to create or draw emoticon image so that I can pass it to a textfield I think this looks pretty much like what I want to achieve. - Shilly

Comment: Just like this :) to create this :)