# how to show tick mark and an overlay on image while clicking an image, but when i click other image it should hide and display the same on new image?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

i want the image to be overlay-ed with any color and give a tick mark on it(As it is selected) allowing only one image at  a time. while clicking other image it should hide the previous one and show tick and overlay on new image.

```
<div class="grid-two imageandtext">
                                    <figure>

                                        <img src="assets/images/painting.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <p>Painting</p>
                                        </div>                     
                                        <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
                                            <img src="assets/images/photography.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" >
                                            <div class="caption1">
                                                <p>Photography</p>
                                            </div></div>
                                        </figure>
                                    </div>
```

it should display like below image

[image: ![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZvgy.jpg]

now it is working like this

[https://jsfiddle.net/liza_susan/L8jyum77/](http://jsfiddle.net/liza_susan/L8jyum77/)

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. You are expected to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question.

Comment: i added a jsfiddle, please excuse the style, i need to show one image as selected.

Comment: Your link is dead :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/liza_susan/2jwc4dph/

Comment: sorry please check this one https://jsfiddle.net/liza_susan/L8jyum77/

Comment: check these answers:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170280/jquery-selecting-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start, using a pseudo element for the *cover*, a `label` and an `input` of type `radio` to take care of the selection.

I wrapped the image in a label, and when clicked, it simply checks the input.

In the CSS, when an input is checked, the `.image_grid input:checked + .caption::after` rule apply the properties to cover and show the check mark.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e9tdx76/3/)

```css
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;                            /*  changed to match image_grid padding  */
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);              /*  changed to match image_grid padding  */
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.caption p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro regular';
  font-size: 15.31px;
}
.imageandtext {
  position: relative;
}
.image_grid {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.image_grid img {                       /*  added rule  */
  display: block;
}
.image_grid input {
  display: none;
}
.image_grid input:checked + .caption {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.image_grid input:checked + .caption::after {
  content: '✔';    
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  width: 70px; height: 70px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-two imageandtext">

  <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
    <label for="selimg1">
      <img src="http://yaitisme.com/images/getImage.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg1">
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Painting</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
    <label for="selimg2">
      <img src="http://yaitisme.com/images/getImage.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="selimg" id="selimg2">
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Photography</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Based on a comment, here is a version where the `caption` is positioned inside the `label`, as a `span` (as `label` can only have inline element as children).

With this one doesn't need unique id on the `input` and can drop the `for` attribute, and no need to compensate for any padding and/or margin set on the `image_grid`.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e9tdx76/5/)

Stack snippet

```css
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.caption span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro regular';
  font-size: 15.31px;
}
.image_grid {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.image_grid label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image_grid img {
  display: block;
}
.image_grid input {
  display: none;
}

.image_grid input:checked + .caption {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.image_grid input:checked + .caption::after {
  content: '✔';    
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  width: 70px; height: 70px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-two imageandtext">

  <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
    <label>
      <img src="http://yaitisme.com/images/getImage.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      <input type="radio" name="selimg">
      <span class="caption">
        <span>Painting</span>
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
    <label>
      <img src="http://yaitisme.com/images/getImage.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      <input type="radio" name="selimg">
      <span class="caption">
        <span>Painting</span>
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what about if i have more images?

Comment: @liza Here is one with 6. Make sure you set unique `id`/`for`, or else it won't work ... https://jsfiddle.net/9e9tdx76/2/

Comment: @liza You are welcome .... and as you now can also vote, an upvote is always appreciated :)

Comment: the  overlay while clicking the image is overflowing, i want to set the overlay inside the image thumbnail

Comment: please check the image in question

Comment: @liza Will have a look

Comment: @liza Updated my answer + this fiddle ... https://jsfiddle.net/9e9tdx76/3/ ... and if you check there is 3 changes made, in CSS, and I added a comment right next to each

Comment: @liza So if you add any border, more padding etc. on the image_grid/label/image, and as the `caption` doesn't _know_ how big the image is, you need to compensate for the same on its rule

Comment: @liza Another option is to change the `caption` and its `p` elements to a `span` (as only inline elements can be a child of a `label`), and move them inside the `label` ... https://jsfiddle.net/9e9tdx76/5/ ... with this, the `caption` is sized by the `label`, and the `label` by the `img`

Comment: the first fiddle was enough..thank you so much LGSon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146145/discussion-between-liza-and-lgson).

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an image when someone hovers over it.

i.e.

```
.image-thumbnail:hover {
    background-image: <path to image>;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: sorry sir, i need the image to be selected like checkboxes, but only one at a time

Answer (score 0):

How about this JQuery function:

```
$('.image_grid').click(function() {
  $('.image_grid img:nth-of-type(2)').hide();
  $(this).children('img:nth-of-type(2)').show();
});
```

```js
$('.image_grid').click(function() {
  $('.image_grid img:nth-of-type(2)').hide();
  $(this).children('img:nth-of-type(2)').show();
});
```

```css
.grid-two {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline;
}
.caption1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -51px;
  left: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Myriad Pro regular;
  font-size: 15.31px;
}
.imageandtext {
  position: relative;
}
.image_grid {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.absolute {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-two imageandtext">
  <figure>
    <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
      <img src="http://yaitisme.com/images/getImage.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      <div class="caption1">
        <p>Painting</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg1Do.png" class="absolute">
    </div>
    <div class="imageandtext image_grid">
      <img src="http://yaitisme.com/images/getImage.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
      <div class="caption1">
        <p>Photography</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg1Do.png" class="absolute">
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/liza_susan/L8jyum77/)